# Get value from nested json php

Tags: php, json

I am receiving data from a webhook with the following code below.

```
<?php
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$myfile = fopen("callback.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = $input["payload"]["type"];

fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);


fclose($myfile);
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

I am trying to get the 'type' value from the retuned output. I have found that using an if statement inside a for each loop would do the job. However i'm sure this isn't an ideal solution. is there a more direct way of getting that element?

The code above is outputting an empty text file.

and the documentation shows the json should be in the following format:

```
{
  "action": "add",
  "collection": "broadcast",
  "payload": {
    "author": "Sveninge Bambuser",
    "created": 1474033783,
    "customData": "",
    "height": 540,
    "id": "9353eaec-794f-11e6-97c0-f19001529702",
    "ingestChannel": "cfc8626c-9a0e-ab78-6424-3eb0978d8e45",
    "lat": 63.205312,
    "length": 0,
    "lon": 17.13011,
    "positionAccuracy": 25,
    "positionType": "GPS",
    "preview": "https://archive.bambuser.com/9353eaec-794f-11e6-97c0-f19001529702.jpg",
    "resourceUri": "https://cdn.bambuser.net/broadcasts/9353eaec-794f-11e6-97c0-f19001529702?da_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&da_id=9353eaec-794f-11e6-97c0-f19001529702&da_timestamp=1474033783&da_static=1&da_ttl=0&da_signature=eaf4c9cb29c58b910dcbad17cf7d8a3afa4e6a963624ba4c4fd0bb5bade1cdd6",
    "tags": [
      {
        "text": "whoa"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Amazing!",
    "type": "live",
    "width": 960
  },
  "eventId": "93df93061a891c23"
}
```

Comment: your `type` value is a string, do you mean the `tags` value?

Comment: Show your exact attempt in the code and provide the resulting output. What you've given as an example seems fine.  [See here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e33b1ba67953b0fa0aaf2a32b4e61e50672fed52)

Comment: Hi, I have amended the question, basically I am getting an empty text file.

Comment: Tip: Name your JSON files with the `.json` extension. Your text editor will love you.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced:

```
$txt = $input["payload"]["type"];
```

with:

```
$txt = $input['payload']['type'];
```

it appears to be the double quotes causing the issue.

Comment: Indent code with four spaces for proper formatting. `>` is used for quoting parts of the original question, not code, and it doesn't apply the correct syntax rules.